# Sql query- needs to extract records based on Datefield

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to extract data from Table1 and insert it into Table2 on Last monday of every month. Basic version of my Tables are something like this..

Table1 (ID,Name,EffectiveDate)

Table2 (ID,Name,EffectiveDate,ProcessDate)

I want to extract only those records where Effectivedate has been 4 months from current date (For Example: if EffectiveDate is 1st January then it should be extracted after 1st April...). Actually Table2 is being used for Reporting purpose so we have 'processDate' field that we can use while Filtering.

Any help would be appreciated..thanks

EDIT:

well, i know we can do something like this

EffectiveDate < DATEADD(MM,-4,GetDate())

Comment: How about DATEADD http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819(v=sql.105).aspx and GETDATE http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: What do you mean by 'it will miss some records'?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE EffectiveDate >= DATEADD(mm, -4, GETDATE())
```

Update:

So you want all records from before 4 months? Then simply switch the < operator:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE EffectiveDate <= DATEADD(mm, -4, GETDATE()) AND processed = 0
```

Update 2:

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM Table1 
    LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID 
WHERE 
    Table1.EffectiveDate <= DATEADD(mm, -4, GETDATE())
    AND Table2.ProcessedDate IS NULL
```

Comment: if you Run this query on 1st April.. it will retreive all records where Effectivedate is later than 1st Jan. I don't want any records from 1st Jan to 1st April. I want records which is older than 1st January and not processed yet..(consider you running query on 1st april for simplicity..)

Comment: @user569711..
Thanks for your Help.. well i don't have Processed(Bit) field in Table1..but is there any way we can use 'ProcessedDate' of Table2?

Comment: +1.. i think logic will give us desired output..do you think it's affect the performance as Table grows..?

Comment: Of course. The more data there is to retrieve, the longer it will take. If you expect a lot of data growth, index the tables properly. I probably also should point out that you should get rid of the * and replace it with the column names you actually need.